# How to get rid of these compiler warnings?

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, compiler-warnings

When I run my code with the below implementation of the Constructor of LRUCache class, I get 12 compiler warnings as follows:

[image: click here to see compiler warnings]

The same set of first six warnings is repeated again.

```
struct Node{
   Node* next;
   Node* prev;
   int value;
   int key;
   Node(Node* p, Node* n, int k, int val):prev(p),next(n),key(k),value(val){};
   Node(int k, int val):prev(NULL),next(NULL),key(k),value(val){};
};

class Cache{

   protected: 
   map<int,Node*> mp;     //map the key to the node in the linked list
   int cp;                //capacity
   Node* tail;            // double linked list tail pointer
   Node* head;            // double linked list head pointer
   virtual void set(int, int) = 0;     //set function
   virtual int get(int) = 0;           //get function

};

class LRUCache : public Cache
{
private:
    int count;
public:
    LRUCache(int capacity)
    {
        cp = capacity;
        tail = NULL;
        head = NULL;
        count = 0;
    }
```

What is wrong with my code?? What should be the proper code implementation so as not to get any warnings??

Comment: That's two warnings, and each one is three lines long.

Comment: It looks like it is saying that your constructor's initialization list isn't in the same order as the members are defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is initialization order in your `Node` struct.

In C++ members are initialized in the order they are declared, regardless the order they are listed in the constructor initializer list.

Thus they are initialized in the order `next`, `prev`, `value`, `key`.

Listing them differently in the constructor can be misleading and thus the warning is telling you to list them there in the same order they are declared.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. This is actually a question code from hackerrank, and I was supposed to implement only the LRUCache class. But when I was trying that on my compiler, it showed me these warnings and I never thought that it is due to their's mistake and not mine, so I didn't look at it. THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR RESPONSE... :)

Comment: Warnings can vary from one compiler to another, and in this case the misordering doesn't cause any problems. It's just a good habit to put them in the right order for those odd occasions when it does matter.